Detect when a class has been renamed or deleted
I am writing a Roslyn incremental generator that will generate TS files based on C# DTOs.
These TS files will be used by a React app so need to be saved to disk and checked into source control - but I don't want to force users of the generator to have to emit generated source files for everything, only these ones.
1: Can I tell Roslyn that the file I have generated must be saved to disk?
1B: If so, can I specify a path?
2: Is there a way to detect when a C# class has been removed or renamed, in case I need to write to disk myself (debounced, obviously).
Or is there a better way to do this (that doesn't involve altering the csproj so it runs an exe after building)?
